# Passing values between activities from a list

Tags: android, bundle, android-intent, simplecursoradapter

I am using SimpleCursoradapter to populate a List that i'm having in an activity.

Now i need to pass a String value from this activity to another and the value is to be fetched from a local database.

I did the same by creating a new textview in the listview and mapping the string value using SimpleCursorAdapter.

Is this the best pratice to do so??

```
public class InboxAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    public InboxAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c,
            String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        Button msgReply = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.msgReply);
        final TextView msgId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.msgId);
        msgReply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            private Intent intent;

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ComposeMessage.class);
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putCharSequence("id", msgId.getText());
                intent.putExtras(b);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: i think that is the best way , pass it with ìntent.putExtras(String yourString);`

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little on short notice, but [this](https://github.com/LukasKnuth/NoteBook/blob/ce81130174218f2b53f206306af8c56da5801342/src/org/knuth/notebook/Main.java#L62) is an example how I managed to do this with a normal `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

The Content is fetched from the Database and shown in the `ListActivity`. This works for `ListView`s, too.

When the user clicks on an item in the list, the [onClick](https://github.com/LukasKnuth/NoteBook/blob/ce81130174218f2b53f206306af8c56da5801342/src/org/knuth/notebook/Main.java#L85)-method gets the items ID from the Database as a parameter. In my example it then opens a new Activity which query's the particular informations from the Database.

Answer (score 1):

i did it this way.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(ClientList.KEY_Client, nameText.getText().toString());//ClientList is another activity
Intent ok=new Intent();
ok.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(RESULT_OK, ok);
finish();
```